# Create bar chart in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this

| Gender | Season | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| male | fall | 300 |
| male | spring | 350 |
| male | summer | 320 |
| male | winter | 305 |
| female | fall | 120 |
| female | spring | 350 |
| female | winter | 320 |
| female | summer | 500 |

Now I would like to create a bar chart in R with 4 different season in which you can see male and female.
Could someone please help me?

Comment: You actually just need `barplot(count ~ Gender + Season, dat)`, read `?barchart` for more options like labels, colors, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a grouped bar would make the most sense here:

```r
df  <- read.table(text = "Gender    Season  count
male    fall    300
male    spring  350
male    summer  320
male    winter  305
female  fall    120
female  spring  350
female  winter  320
female  summer  500", header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
    data = df,
    mapping = aes(
        x = Season,
        y = count
    )) + 
    geom_bar(
        mapping = aes(fill = Gender), 
        position = "dodge",
        stat = "identity"
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Gender, y = count)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~Season)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Season), y=count, fill=Gender))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_text(aes(x = Season, y = count, label = count, group = Gender),
            position = position_stack(vjust = .5), size=5, color="yellow")+
  xlab('Season') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("maroon", "blue"))+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]